# Leaflet is behaving unexpectedly when trying to load more than one layer

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet, jquery, ajax

I had a hard time trying to create a good title for my issue since it is a little hard to explain. But I will do my best.

I'm trying to create a web map to show three distinct layers, each from a different time period. The user choose a year and then the layer is loaded. For this to happen Geoserver is serving three layers using WFS. Now what follows is weird.

- Sometimes when the web map is loaded, or refreshed, some layers are not encoded.
- Sometimes layers end-up in the wrong year option.
- But sometimes everything works, but requires that I refresh the page several times.

My code is not behaving as it should all the time. At first I thought that this should be something related to Geoserver (I posted this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134238/geoserver-sometimes-does-not-load-all-selected-layers) a while ago following this line of though). But now I suspect that the issue is in my Javascript code, I friend of mine mentioned something relate to syncronous and asycrounouns code but I have not idea how to start debugging it.

This is my code (**changed a few things to make it easier to read**):

http://plnkr.co/edit/g1bHqJ1F2TcOlzieW1G8

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Mapping Past Denver</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Plugins/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Plugins/Leaflet.label-master/dist/leaflet.label.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Plugins/fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.css" />
<script src="Plugins/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="Plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Plugins/Leaflet.label-master/dist/leaflet.label.js"></script>
<script src="Plugins/fullscreen/Control.FullScreen.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var map = L.map('map', {
                fullscreenControl: true,
                fullscreenControlOptions: {
                    position: 'topleft'
                }
            }).setView([39.752171, -104.998817], 17);

            //the base map
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 20,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
            }).addTo(map);

            //create the datasets that will hold the layers      
            var dataset1 = new L.layerGroup();
            var dataset2 = new L.layerGroup();
            var dataset3 = new L.layerGroup();
            //JSON request 
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset3&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (response) {
                    WFSLayers = L.geoJson(response, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                                weight: 5,
                                color: '#6e7ce8',
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            };
                        },
                        onEachFeature: effects
                    }).addTo(dataset1);
                }
            });


            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset1&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (response) {
                    WFSLayer2 = L.geoJson(response, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                                weight: 5,
                                color: '#e31424',
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            };
                        },
                        onEachFeature: effects
                    }).addTo(dataset2);
                }
            });


            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset2&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
                success: function (response) {
                    WFSLayer3 = L.geoJson(response, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                                weight: 5,
                                color: '#14e324',
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                dashArray: '3',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                            };
                        },
                        onEachFeature: effects
                    }).addTo(dataset3);
                }
            });


            //hover effect and popup effect
            function effects(feature, layer) {
                popupOptions = {
                    maxWidth: 200
                };
                if (feature.properties.name !== null) {
                    layer.bindLabel(feature.properties.name, popupOptions, {
                        noHide: true
                    });
                };
                layer.bindPopup("<b>Name: </b>" + feature.properties.name + "<br><b>Description: </b>" + feature.properties.descr + "<br><b>Floors: </b>" + feature.properties.floors + "<br><b>Material: </b>" + feature.properties.material);
                layer.on({
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });
            };


            //zoom to feature
            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }

            //group the datasets
            var overlayData = {
                "1887": dataset1,
                "1925": dataset2,
                "1961": dataset3
            };


            //create the layer control
            L.control.layers(overlayData, null, {
                collapsed: false
            }).addTo(map);

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

---

I did some quick research and it seems that the part that may causing issue is the AJAX call, more and more I'm suspecting that this a case of asynchronous code. Still, I haven't found a clear way to fix it. Also, I don't understand why my ajax calls are putting the data in different variables (sometime 1887 data is attributed to dataset3).

---

It seems that the issue is indeed AJAX making the requests at the same time. But yet, I haven't find a clear way to fix this issue. Probably deferred objects is the best solution here but I'm finding trouble applying it to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeking for a more broad (jQuery and AJAX related) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28770332/issues-with-multiple-ajax-calls-requesting-jsonp) I assigned to my `jsonpCallbacks` unique values, like the following:

```
//JSON request 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PastDenver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=PastDenver:dataset3&maxFeatures=300&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:getJson1",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonpCallback: 'getJson1',
                    success: function (response) {
                        WFSLayers = L.geoJson(response, {
                            style: function (feature) {
                                return {
                                    weight: 5,
                                    color: '#6e7ce8',
                                    weight: 2,
                                    opacity: 1,
                                    dashArray: '3',
                                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                                };
                            },
                            onEachFeature: effects
                        }).addTo(dataset1);
                    }
                });
```

For each layer I assigned a specific callback name. Now everything seems to be working just fine, doesn't matter hoe many time I refresh the page, no errors are thrown into the console.

I will make this an answer since it solved my problem, not sure if this is a logical fix or not though.

Answer (score 2):

Two pieces of advice (which may or may not constitute an answer--haven't tested your code myself):

### Use Promise Objects

Available within jQuery (as well as many other js libraries).  Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/): essentially, a promise object allows you to work with variables that point to data that may still be loading asynchronously.

E.g.

```
var promiseData = $.Deferred();

$.ajax(url, {
  success: function(data){
    promiseData.resolve(data);
    // optionally, do other stuff with the data once it's fully loaded
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    promiseData.reject(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

To interact with the promise object outside of the `$.ajax()` success callback, use the [`.done()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

```
promiseData.done(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

### Abstract Code into Functions

There's a lot of different ways to do this, but if you see yourself writing the same code over and over, chances are you could encapsulate that logic once in a function that you call with different argument parameters.

One approach would be something like:

```
var loadData = function(url, styleFunction){
  var wfsLayer = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson',
    success: function(data){
      wfsLayer = L.geojson(data, {
        style: styleFunction,
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
          <insert onEachFeature code>
        }
      }).addTo(dataSet1);
    }
  });

  return promiseData;
};
```

Then call the function with the correct arguments

```
var firstDataSet = loadData('http://localhost:8080...', function(feature){
  return {
    weight: 5,
    color: '#6e7ce8',
    opacity: 1
  };
});
```

and because we're working with promise objects, if you need to interact with firstDataSet, use the `.done()` handler.

There are likely still bugs in the code that this doesn't address, but organizing your code better should make it a lot easier to spot them.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So if I want to manipulate the data once it is loaded outside the ajax call I add it to the dataset using the .done handler? How can I add the Json to a data set using the .done handler?

Comment: By 'dataset' you mean a `L.layerGroup` object?  In that case, probably best to create the object within the ajax success callback:  `promiseData.resolve(L.layerGroup(data));` .  It's entirely possible that you will never need to use the `.done()` handler.  The two safe places to interact with asynchronously loaded data are either w/i the success callback defined within the ajax call, *or* outside of the ajax call and within the `.done()` handler.  Try rewriting your code and share as a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) for specific feedback.

Comment: I did some re-arranging in the code, here is the latest format http://plnkr.co/edit/g1bHqJ1F2TcOlzieW1G8 I couldn't quite understand how to applied deferred objects in it, but it seems that this is easiest way to fix the bug. What I don't understand is why data that is supposed to got to a specif var ends in another.

Answer (score 1):

Your map is being shown in the browser before all the GeoJSON is loaded into your layers.

Try wrapping your JavaScript with jQuery's ready() method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  <put all your code in here>

 });
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and the error persists. Not sure if in the same degree of occurrence. Should I post the code updated?

Comment: This works in my case, so all the data loads. But it leads to a problem, i can't click on my polygon layers anymore, don't know yet how it interferes with these layers. I think it might have to do with time delays built into these layers.

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer, but it seems like the answer may be very specific to OP's particular code.

If anyone else is having trouble loading more than 1 leaflet layer with this whole asynchronous/synchronous problem, here is a solution I found and have tested for my personal use. It's working perfectly for me.

**My problem:** A leaflet map is supposed to load and display 3 geojson files, but often fails to load and display the third geojson file when the map is refreshed, seemingly randomly.

**Solution in brief:** Instead of using jquery/AJAX, use the `Fetch API` to return a promise object. I specifically followed the code from [this github page](https://gist.github.com/blahah/167a363844326c2192d7ab0ff32ad8d0).

Okay, so here are the specifics.

My original problematic code looked like this. It was being used to load and display a locally stored geojson file of hotel locations (point data). It was problematic and only loaded intermittently:

```
var hotels = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hotels.open(
        "GET",
        "/data/hotel_hostel_guestHouse.geojson",
    );
    hotels.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    hotels.responseType = "json";
    hotels.onload = function() {
        if (beaches.status != 200) return;
        L.geoJSON(hotels.response).addTo(mymap)
        };
    hotels.send();
```

Okay, now here's code that works everytime using the `Fetch API`. It uses arrow functions for brevity.

If someone wants to copy and paste this, you're going to want to rename `hotel_url` to something more suitable for your use case, and change the url itself to point to your data. You'll also need to change the name of the variable `mymap` to your specific `mapid`.

```
var hotel_url = "/data/hotel_hostel_guestHouse.geojson"

    fetch(
        hotel_url
    ).then(
        res => res.json()
    ).then(
        data => L.geoJson(data).addTo(mymap)
    )
```